# Bought game on Steam, but it's not in my Library

Tags: steam

I bought a game on my dad's chrome book yesterday on steam and it told me to check my library for the games I bought, but they are not showing up. Do I have to buy them again? Or is there a way to download them, even though I didn't install them on the chrome book? Also, I was positive that I was on my account because I see them on the previous transactions thing, but they are not showing up.

Comment: Did they somehow get put into your Inventory instead?

Comment: I checked and they were not there

Comment: Check your Account Details to make sure the licenses were added. You can see this by clicking the down arrow next to your avatar in the upper right.

Comment: I check and then I checked the library and they were there so there could have been a lag in the servers or something but THANK YOU :D

Comment: Tried that and was asking for a refund so I am waiting for it. And when I checked the library it was not even there, not a single game that i bought.

Answer (score 10):

It's also possible that your library has been set to filter by "Installed" so it isn't showing the newly purchased game. Make sure the dropdown by the Library header button is set to All Games.

[image: Installed]

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a similar thing before, especially in times of peak load on the Steam servers (Summer or Christmas Sales) or when the Steam client has been updated. FYI - my Steam client updated in the last 24 hours also so that may have something to do with it.

Patch release notes and for future reference at: [Steam News](http://store.steampowered.com/news/?feed=steam_client%20Steam%20News)

This question could probably be resolved as it sounds like your game is appearing now :)

Answer (score 1):

So if games do now show up in library, be sure to log out of your account, then log back in. In most cases it is a simple lagging error. hope this helps!